# SQL CASE Logic Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Could someone please assist me? Example: Problem I am having is when an account has AV.Query='PN4', AV.Response = 'Y', AV.Query='FL1' and AV.Response='Y', the result needs to be

```
PStatus   IStatus
4         2
```

However, I am getting

```
PStatus    IStatus
4          5
5          2
```

It picks "5" all the time on the opposite column.

```
SELECT distinct  A.AcctNum,
      CASE 
        WHEN O.Order = 'NEI2' THEN '1'
        WHEN AV.Query IN ('PNE1','PNE2') AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '2'
        WHEN AV.Query = 'PN20' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '3'
        WHEN AV.Query = 'PN4' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '4'
      ELSE '5'
         END AS [PStatus],

    CASE   
        WHEN O.Order IN ('DO2','FL25','VACHP') THEN '1'
        WHEN AV.Query = 'FL1' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '2'
            WHEN AV.Query = 'REF' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '3'
        WHEN AV.Query IN ('FL2','FL6','NEU.G','HE.B') AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '4'
        WHEN AV.Query = 'NOA' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '6'
    ELSE '5'
    END AS [IStatus]

FROM AData AS AD 

        INNER JOIN AVisit AS AV
         ON AD.Visit = AV.Visit
      AND AV.QueryID IN ('PNE1','PNE2','PN20','PN4','FL1','REF','FL2','FL6','NEU.G','HE.B','NOA')

        LEFT JOIN Order AS O
     ON AD.Visit = O.Visit
         AND O.Order IN ('NEI2','DO2','FL25','VACHP');
```

Comment: Can you put up sql fiddle with your data as its very difficult to analyse without data?

Comment: What is sql fiddle? Thank you.

Comment: Go to this  website and create table and insert data. When finished give us url 
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Did you try googling SQL FIddle?

Comment: Are you certain those are the values of the record?  Have you tried running a `SELECT` statement on just those columns to make sure their value?

Comment: I don't see how they could ever be the same. Both case statements check AV.Query and none of the values AV.Query is being compared to are the same across the statements.

Comment: Are the 'accounts' stored in the AData table?

Comment: Account numbers are stored in AData, Queries and responses are stored in AVisit table. Some queries are from Order table. Order table does not have response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your results appear to be correct for the query.

Consider first the row of the join that has

> AV.Query='PN4', AV.Response = 'Y',

This matches the last `WHEN` condition in the `CASE` expression for `[PStatus]`, but it does not match any of the `WHEN` conditions in the `CASE` expression for `[IStatus]`.  Result:

```
4  5
```

Consider now the join row having

> AV.Query='FL1' and AV.Response='Y'

This does not match any `WHEN` condition in the `CASE` expression for `[PStatus]`, but it matches the second `WHEN` conditions in the `CASE` expression for `[IStatus]`.  Result:

```
5  2
```

I could give you a variation on your query that produces the results you specified for the particular data you present, but I do not do so because there are many alternatives, and you haven't given us the information to determine which one correctly answers the question for other data.

**UPDATE:**

To combine multiple result rows into one, you require an aggregate query.  One possible way to implement such a query to provide a single row having values 4, 2 for your given data would be

```
SELECT
  AcctNum,
  MIN(
    CASE 
      WHEN O.Order = 'NEI2' THEN '1'
      WHEN AV.Query IN ('PNE1','PNE2') AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '2'
      WHEN AV.Query = 'PN20' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '3'
      WHEN AV.Query = 'PN4' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '4'
      ELSE NULL
    END
  ) AS [Pstatus],
  MIN(
    CASE   
      WHEN O.Order IN ('DO2','FL25','VACHP') THEN '1'
      WHEN AV.Query = 'FL1' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '2'
      WHEN AV.Query = 'REF' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '3'
      WHEN AV.Query IN ('FL2','FL6','NEU.G','HE.B') AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '4'
      WHEN AV.Query = 'NOA' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '6'
      ELSE NULL
    END
  ) AS [IStatus]
FROM
  AData AS AD 
  INNER JOIN AVisit AS AV
    ON AD.Visit = AV.Visit
      AND AV.QueryID IN ('PNE1','PNE2','PN20','PN4','FL1','REF','FL2','FL6','NEU.G','HE.B','NOA')

  LEFT JOIN Order AS O
    ON AD.Visit = O.Visit
      AND O.Order IN ('NEI2','DO2','FL25','VACHP');
GROUP BY AcctNum
```

This works because aggregate functions other than `COUNT()` ignore `NULL`s.  It very likely will not give the desired answer for different data patterns, however -- especially patterns where there are more than two `AVisit`s for the same account.

Comment: Exactly John, so how do I fix that? Any alternative will work as long as I get the correct result and I don't get "5" added all the time.

Comment: Every Query has Response "Y" or "N". I only need queries that has "Y" response. This example account had AV.Query='PN4' and AV.Query='FL1' with "Y" response. So result should only be 4  2.

Comment: You are computing two separate result columns, assigned labels `PStatus` and `IStatus`.  Are you saying you want only one, instead?

Comment: Or are you trying to *combine* multiple result rows into one?

Comment: I need 2 new columns, which I am naming PStatus and IStatus.

Comment: I updated my answer with a query that does as you describe.  I emphasize, however, that this is pretty much a shot in the dark.  You could also satisfy your stated requirement by changing your original query's entire `SELECT` clause to `SELECT DISTINCT AcctNum, 4 AS [PStatus], 2 AS [IStatus]`.

Comment: I think your answer is correct. Let me verify. The other answer that I had previously marked had excluded so many accounts which needs to be included.

Comment: For one account, I have "FL1", "DO2", and "NEI2" so I was expecting 1,1 and 5,4 but it only gave me 1,1.

Comment: Note that in my answer I specifically called out such a limitation.  "Any alternative will work as long as I get the correct result" -- @Bulbul.  Apparently not.  I am done guessing about what you actually want.

Comment: John! I was still trying to make it perfect. Some accounts might have one query with 'Y' response, some account might have 3 queries with 'Y' response. What if some account has 3 queries? Example: 'NEI2', 'PN4', 'FL1'. This query gets only the MIN values so it will get the first correct row. However, it will not include a record which will be in the second row.

Answer (score 1):

Results are correct.

Your values are:

First row -  `AV.Query='PN4'`, `AV.Response = 'Y'`
Second row - `AV.Query='FL1', AV.Response='Y'`

First CASE PStatus: Result is 4 as you expected.

Next Case, Istatus. Here is probably lying misunderstanding, Because SQL will process still the same values (First row). This `CASE` will check against values: `AV.Query='PN4'`, `AV.Response = 'Y'` from first line. Not against your second values (`AV.Query='FL1' and AV.Response='Y'`).

Values `'PN4' and 'FL1'` can not be in same Column in a same line! One column can have only one value, not two. You are probably expecting that in this second case SQL will start fetching another (second) line of data. But it is not.

Second case result is correct Because in the CASE there is not condition for value `PN4`, so it is end up as `ELSE = 5`

---

OK Edit, do it like this, this brute force, but will work ;-)

```
   SELECT A.AcctNum,
     COALESCE(MAX( CASE 
        WHEN O.Order = 'NEI2' THEN '1'
        WHEN AV.Query IN ('PNE1','PNE2') AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '2'
        WHEN AV.Query = 'PN20' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '3'
        WHEN AV.Query = 'PN4' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '4'
      ELSE NULL
         END),5) AS [PStatus],

    COALESCE(MAX(CASE   
        WHEN O.Order IN ('DO2','FL25','VACHP') THEN '1'
        WHEN AV.Query = 'FL1' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '2'
        WHEN AV.Query = 'REF' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '3'
        WHEN AV.Query IN ('FL2','FL6','NEU.G','HE.B') AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '4'
        WHEN AV.Query = 'NOA' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '6'
    ELSE NULL
    END),5) AS [IStatus]
```

Comment: Yes, I understand the problem. But, how can I fix it? Any suggestion or code you can type for me? Thank you.

Comment: For one account, I have "FL1", "DO2", and "NEI2" so I was expecting 1,1 and 5,4 but it only gave me 1,4 using "MAX" (Your query). Using "MIN" (John's query above) I got 1,1. The right answer needs to be 1,4 and 5,1 or 1,1 and 5,4.

Comment: Hmm, provide us all raw data for particular Account, use below query:

`SELECT * FROM 
  AData AS AD 
  INNER JOIN AVisit AS AV
    ON AD.Visit = AV.Visit
      AND AV.QueryID IN ('PNE1','PNE2','PN20','PN4','FL1','REF','FL2','FL6','NEU.G','HE.B','NOA')

  LEFT JOIN Order AS O
    ON AD.Visit = O.Visit
      AND O.Order IN ('NEI2','DO2','FL25','VACHP')

WHERE AcctNum = '`*insert_the_accunt_which_cusing_trouble*`'`

Comment: Select * will try produce almost 50 rows and I can't put it here due to work privacy. That's why I summarized the logic in my question here.

Comment: Please check this out for more clarification: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311963/case-statement-logic-not-fully-functional