# Case Statement Logic Not Fully Functional

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Below are some example results that I am expecting from my script:
Example 1: Customer 12 was provided only service 'NEI2'. then result should be

```
AcctNum  PStatus  IStatus
12       1        5
```

Example 2: If customer 21 had service 'PN20', 'PN4', and 'FL1' then the result should be

```
AcctNum  PStatus  IStatus
    21       3        2
    21       4        5
```

Response will always be 'Y'. You can modify the script if you need to. Thank you.

Below is the script:

```
    SELECT distinct  A.AcctNum,
      CASE 
        WHEN O.Order = 'NEI2' THEN '1'
        WHEN AV.Query IN ('PNE1','PNE2') AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '2'
        WHEN AV.Query = 'PN20' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '3'
        WHEN AV.Query = 'PN4' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '4'
      ELSE '5'
         END AS [PStatus],

    CASE   
        WHEN O.Order IN ('DO2','FL25','VACHP') THEN '1'
        WHEN AV.Query = 'FL1' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '2'
            WHEN AV.Query = 'REF' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '3'
        WHEN AV.Query IN ('FL2','FL6','NEU.G','HE.B') AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '4'
        WHEN AV.Query = 'NOA' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '6'
    ELSE '5'
    END AS [IStatus]

FROM AData AS AD 

        INNER JOIN AVisit AS AV
         ON AD.Visit = AV.Visit
      AND AV.QueryID IN ('PNE1','PNE2','PN20','PN4','FL1','REF','FL2','FL6','NEU.G','HE.B','NOA')

        LEFT JOIN Order AS O
     ON AD.Visit = O.Visit
         AND O.Order IN ('NEI2','DO2','FL25','VACHP');
```

Comment: What is the values of `AcctNum` in your question resulting in only one row upon grouping?

Comment: There are so many different account numbers. Some account numbers have one query, some have 2 or 3 queries. The response will always be 'Y'.

Comment: Sorry, i am not following. What is the meaning of the information produced in the "correct result"? How should the result be interpreted / read by an user?

Comment: Have added my answer to your question based on the extent of my understanding of your requirement.

Comment: Different queries and order means different services provided. So customers have been provided different services. I need to find which customer received which service. Example: if customer A received 'NEI2','DO2','REF' then the result will be like 1,1 and 5,3.

Comment: Please do me a favor and paste some data from your query with the `group by` and `min` removed?

Comment: I modified the script. Does that help? Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70229/discussion-between-chris-du-preez-and-bulbul).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the `group by` by the statuses?

```
SELECT AcctNum,
       (CASE WHEN O.Order = 'NEI2' THEN '1'
             WHEN AV.Query IN ('PNE1','PNE2') AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '2'
             WHEN AV.Query = 'PN20' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '3'
             WHEN AV.Query = 'PN4' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '4'
             ELSE NULL
        END) AS [Pstatus],
       (CASE WHEN O.Order IN ('DO2','FL25','VACHP') THEN '1'
             WHEN AV.Query = 'FL1' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '2'
             WHEN AV.Query = 'REF' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '3'
             WHEN AV.Query IN ('FL2','FL6','NEU.G','HE.B') AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '4'
             WHEN AV.Query = 'NOA' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '6'
             ELSE NULL
        END) AS [IStatus]
FROM AData AS AD INNER JOIN
     AVisit AS AV
     ON AD.Visit = AV.Visit 
WHERE AV.QueryID IN ('PNE1', 'PNE2', 'PN20', 'PN4', 'FL1', 'REF', 'FL2','FL6', 'NEU.G','HE.B','NOA') LEFT JOIN
     Order AS O
     ON AD.Visit = O.Visit AND O.Order IN ('NEI2','DO2','FL25','VACHP');
GROUP BY AcctNum, 
       (CASE WHEN O.Order = 'NEI2' THEN '1'
             WHEN AV.Query IN ('PNE1','PNE2') AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '2'
             WHEN AV.Query = 'PN20' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '3'
             WHEN AV.Query = 'PN4' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '4'
             ELSE NULL
        END) AS [Pstatus],
       (CASE WHEN O.Order IN ('DO2','FL25','VACHP') THEN '1'
             WHEN AV.Query = 'FL1' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '2'
             WHEN AV.Query = 'REF' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '3'
             WHEN AV.Query IN ('FL2','FL6','NEU.G','HE.B') AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '4'
             WHEN AV.Query = 'NOA' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '6'
             ELSE NULL
        END) AS [IStatus];
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, I modified my initial question with examples of the results that I am expecting. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your query to `group by` `AcctNum`, and values of `[Pstatus]` and `[IStatus]`.

Do not believe it is possible to achieve what you are suggesting in example 2 - i.e producing a SQL grouping/merging rule to consolidate row values (3,5)(4,5)(5,2) into (3,2)(4,5):

> Example 2: If customer 21 had service 'PN20', 'PN4', and 'FL1' then
>   the result should be

```
AcctNum  PStatus  IStatus
     21       3        2
     21       4        5
```

> 

My suggestion is to group your data to `AcctNum`, and values of `[Pstatus]` and `[IStatus]` because anything "more" would require complexity beyond it's worth:

```
SELECT
      AcctNum,
      (CASE 
          WHEN O.Order = 'NEI2' THEN '1'
          WHEN AV.Query IN ('PNE1','PNE2') AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '2'
          WHEN AV.Query = 'PN20' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '3'
          WHEN AV.Query = 'PN4' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '4'
          ELSE '5'
        END
      ) AS [Pstatus],
      (CASE   
          WHEN O.Order IN ('DO2','FL25','VACHP') THEN '1'
          WHEN AV.Query = 'FL1' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '2'
          WHEN AV.Query = 'REF' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '3'
          WHEN AV.Query IN ('FL2','FL6','NEU.G','HE.B') AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '4'
          WHEN AV.Query = 'NOA' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '6'
          ELSE '5'
        END
      ) AS [IStatus]
    FROM AData AS AD 
    INNER JOIN AVisit AS AV ON AD.Visit = AV.Visit AND 
               AV.QueryID IN ('PNE1','PNE2','PN20','PN4','FL1','REF','FL2','FL6','NEU.G','HE.B','NOA')

    LEFT JOIN Order AS O ON AD.Visit = O.Visit AND 
              O.Order IN ('NEI2','DO2','FL25','VACHP');

    GROUP BY AcctNum,
      (CASE 
          WHEN O.Order = 'NEI2' THEN '1'
          WHEN AV.Query IN ('PNE1','PNE2') AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '2'
          WHEN AV.Query = 'PN20' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '3'
          WHEN AV.Query = 'PN4' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '4'
          ELSE '5'
        END),
      (CASE   
          WHEN O.Order IN ('DO2','FL25','VACHP') THEN '1'
          WHEN AV.Query = 'FL1' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '2'
          WHEN AV.Query = 'REF' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '3'
          WHEN AV.Query IN ('FL2','FL6','NEU.G','HE.B') AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '4'
          WHEN AV.Query = 'NOA' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '6'
          ELSE '5'
        END)
```

Comment: Hi Chris! I modified my question. Please have a look at it and help if you can. Thank you.